# How to pass a reference to a callback function for use in array_filter with extra arguments?

Tags: php, reference, pass-by-reference

The signature for my method looks like this:

```
public function ProgramRuleFilter(&$program, $today=null) {
```

When I invoke it like this,

```
$programs = array_filter($programs, array($this,'ProgramRuleFilter'));
```

Everything works as expected. The `ProgramRuleFilter` method updates the `$program` array and then returns true/false if it succeeded which correctly filters `$programs`.

However, now I want to pass an extra argument to the filter, `$today`. How can I do that?

I'm trying to invoke it like this:

```
$programs = array_filter($programs, new CallbackArgs(array($this,'ProgramRuleFilter'),$today));
```

Using this little class as a wrapper:

```
class CallbackArgs {
    private $callback;
    private $args;

    function __construct() {
        $args = func_get_args();
        $this->callback = array_shift($args);
        $this->args = $args;
    }

    function __invoke(&$arg) {
        return call_user_func_array($this->callback, array_merge(array($arg),$this->args));
    }
}
```

But the programs aren't being updated, so somewhere along the line it lost the reference to the original object. I'm not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 10):

The second argument to `array_filter` must be a callback; which means that `array_filter` itself will be calling your filter function. There is no way to tell `array_filter` to call that function in any other way, so you'll need to find a way to get the value of `$today` into your function some other way.

This is a perfect example of when to use a closure, which will let you bind some data (in this case, the value of `$today`) into a function / callback. Assuming you are using PHP 5.3 or later:

```
// Assuming $today has already been set

$object = $this; // PHP 5.4 eliminates the need for this
$programs = array_filter( $programs, function( $x ) use ( $today, $object ){
    return $object->ProgramRuleFilter( $x, $today );
});
```

This defines a closure inline, using the values of `$today` and `$object` from the parent scope, and then just calls your existing function `ProgramRuleFilter` on that $object. (The somewhat unusual `$object = $this` gets around the fact that otherwise, the closure would not be able to call a method on your object instance. But in PHP 5.4, you can replace `$object` with `$this` inside the closure.)

Now, this is a somewhat inelegant way to do it, because all this closure does is hand off the work to the `ProgramRuleFilter` function. A better way would be to use the closure instead of the function. So:

```
// Assuming $today has already been set

$filter = function( $x ) use ( $today ){
    // Cut and paste the contents of ProgramRuleFilter() here,
    // and make it operate on $x and $today
};
$programs = array_filter( $programs, $filter );
```

Which variation works best for you will depend on the implementation of the rest of your app. Good luck!

Comment: `$x` needs to be a reference; I'm assuming you meant to use `function(&$x)`, but otherwise, this looks like it would work. I knew you weren't allowed to pass `$this` into a closure in 5.3.x which is why I didn't try this approach, but it never occurred to me to just assign it to another variable beforehand.

Comment: +1 But I don't think using a closure to call another function is inelegant. It's a nice way to decorate the functionality.

Comment: However, I would suggest making the method static and avoid closing in the object.

Comment: I run this filter in a couple different places BTW, so it's nicer not to have to rewrite the closure every time.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a new method to handle it:

```
public static function array_filter_args($array, $callback) {
    $args = array_slice(func_get_args(),2);
    foreach($array as $key=>&$value) {
        if(!call_user_func_array($callback, array_merge(array(&$value),$args))) {
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Called like this:

```
$programs = ArrayHelper::array_filter_args($programs, array($this,'ProgramRuleFilter'), $today);
```

I didn't know you could do this `array(&$value)`, but I thought I'd try it, and it looks like it works. I'm guessing that `array_merge` is the culprit that dereferences the variable otherwise.